# Segmentation fault while initializing vector by an initialized array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl-algorithm

I wanted to use the **sort()** in the **algorithm library** in C++. I could find examples for **sorting vectors only**, thus I am trying to initialize a vector by an initialized array. When executing I am getting a segmentation fault and couldn't figure out what is wrong here in the code I wrote.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int n,k,packet[1000],min=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&k);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    scanf("%d",&packet[i]);
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
cout<<"debug";
vector<int> packets(packet,packet+n);
vector<int>::iterator start,stop;
sort(packets.begin(),packets.begin()+n);

min=*(packets.begin())- *(packets.end());
cout<<min;
for (vector<int>::iterator it=packets.begin(); it!=packets.end()-k; ++it)
{
    printf("%d  ",*it );
    if((*(it+k) - *it)<min)
    {
        start=it;
        stop=it+k;
    }
}
printf("%d\n",*stop- *start );

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You can use `std::sort` with an array just fine. The same iterators you initialize the vector with are what you pass to the algorithm.

Comment: How do you get segmentation fault while compiling?

Comment: For sort, use "sort(packets.begin(), packets.end());" if that's what you mean.

Comment: If you are getting a segfault while compiling, you have a compiler error, then you need to post: which compiler, which operating system, what command line arguments and all of the compiler output from your compilation.

Comment: I've a strong feeling that its a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @Kunal sorry, my bad. While executing.

Comment: Then soon has already answered it but I'll post a way to clean up the code a great deal.

Comment: @Shivendra I've cleaned up the code but I'm not sure what "k" is - it looks like you are somehow trying to find the lowest time between packets? But maybe this cleanup will help you focus on solving the problem rather than the implementation: http://ideone.com/6i6I6z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*(packets.end())
```

`packets.end()` returns an iterator to the element, following the last element of the vector.

Attempting to derefenrence it causes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I have always used as you mentioned except when I didn't want the dereferenced value.

Comment: Sorry, got it. Thanks. packet.end()-1 will do?

Comment: @Shivendra why not use `packet.back()` if you want reference to the last element.

Answer (score 1):

The comments explain that you can use sort with an array just fine (if you look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort you'll see that `sort` takes two arguments that: `-RandomIt must meet the requirements of ValueSwappable and RandomAccessIterator.`. Plain pointers fulfill this requirement).

In your example, the segfault happens because you try to dereference a `valid but undereferencable` iterator (the iterator returned by 'end()' in: `min=*(packets.begin())- *(packets.end());`. Basically it returns an iterator that points to `after` the last element of the vector. If you want to get an iterator to the last element, you can use `rbegin()` but of course you need to make sure that the vector is **not empty** first).

You could have seen this quite easily by running your code under a debugger, you'd see that the *segmentation fault* had nothing to do with the call to `sort`